# nginx error pages not working in angular app using routes

Tags: angularjs, nginx, error-handling, custom-pages

I have an angular app that uses routes, where it has `.otherwise(){}` in **routes.js** file and now I need to make custom error pages using nginx, how to stop the `.otherwise(){}` and use the error pages defined on nginx **default** file, Anyone Please help I'm working on it from 5hrs. Or point me to any link that explains and solves this problem.

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular?

Comment: I'm using angular js

Comment: when using angularjs, please tag the correct angular tag

Comment: @mast3rd3mon apologies for that. Any solution for the above

Answer (score 0):

"Otherwise" in the routing is looking for a client side route. You can probably direct otherwise to a separate route on the client side with a controller that automatically redirects to a server route.

```
 .otherwise('/ControllerThatSendsToServer');
```

Then in the ControllerThatSendsToServer just do a window.location = 'server error page';